# my DetailView cannot load image

Tags: ios, objective-c

.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
      IBOutlet UILabel *sname; 
      IBOutlet UIImageView *sImage;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic)id titletwo;
@property (strong, nonatomic)id Viewimage;
```

.m

```
@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.Viewimage description]];
    sImage.image = theImage;

    sname.text = [self.titletwo description];

}
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)tableViewUITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPathNSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetailViewController *view2 = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

    view2.Viewimage = [tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail];
    view2.titletwo = [tmpDict objectForKey:name];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

my title can get a data and show it! but the image can 't what can i do?

Comment: What type of object is `thumbnail`? What does `[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]` return?

Answer (score 0):

Thee problem is with following line of code

```
   DetailViewController *view2 = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

as you are initialising DetailViewController with nib pointed to nil.

Specified nib name here

```
DetailViewController *view2 = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SPECIFIED NIB NAME HERE" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you should consider using **only ARC** in your program. In .h you're defining your property as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)id titletwo;
```

using **stong** but then in ViewController you're using `autorelease`:

```
DetailViewController *view2 = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

**Second**: things to check: put a breakpoint at `view2.Viewimage = [tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail];`and print the content of `[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]`writing in lldb window:

```
po [tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]
```

That will print the value returned. If it's nil, there's no key thumbnail in that object. Maybe you misspell that `thumbnail` constant.

**Third**: self.ViewImage looks like a UIImage, but you're using description here. Are you sure you know which type is everything? You're using ids...

Comment: view2 DetailViewController * 0x07177080
UIViewController UIViewController 
sname UILabel * 0x00000000
sImage UIImageView * 0x00000000
_titletwo id 0x00000000
_Viewimage id 0x00000000

Comment: So everything is nil at some point (you're not giving that information, that is, in which line did you print that log). If you send a message to nil, nothing happens.